# textscan introduces additional zeros in output array

Tags: matlab

I have a .txt file like this:

ord,cat,1

ord,cat,1

ord,cat,3

ord,cat,1

ord,cat,4

I know the number of entries for each row (comma separated) but not the number of rows.
I need to import the number of the following car in an array.
I wrote this:

```
fid=fopen(filename)

A=textscan(fid,'%s%s%d','Delimiter',',')
```

But i get this

```
A =  {17x1 cell}    [16x1 int32]
```

where the number of cells is clearly wrong.
When i try to read

```
A{3}
```

i get

```
ans =

       0
       0
       0
       0
       0
       1
       0
       1
       0
       3
       0
       1
       0
       4
```

I'm really interested just in the integer array, but maybe can be useful to show you also:

A{1}

```
ans = 

'{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1187\cocoasubrtf400'
'{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}'
'{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}'
[1x75  char]
[1x102 char]
'\f0\fs24 \cf0 ord'
'\'         
'ord'       
'\'         
'ord'       
'\'         
'ord'       
'\'         
'ord'       
'}'
```

A{2}

```
ans = 

''
''
''
''
''
'cat'
''
'cat'
''
'cat'
''
'cat'
''
'cat'
```

Ok,I think there was a format mistake of some kind in the input file.
I deleted it and created a new .txt file and the code above works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You're not giving the right format command to `textscan`.

`A=textscan(fid,'%s%d','Delimiter',',')`

`'%s%d'` here means "read one string, then one integer".  So it will probably sit there reading string-integer-string-integer (or trying to), and the "0"s arise from errors where

Since you have three entries per line, try instead:

`A=textscan(fid,'%s%s%d','Delimiter',',')`

Your numbers should be in `A{3}`.

If you don't need the first two columns, you can also skip over those fields:

`A=textscan(fid,'%*s%*s%d','Delimiter',',')`

Comment: hi! thank you for your kind answer. I fixed the format mistake you say here, it was a typo due to an other file i was working on. But the output problem is still there, unaffected.